# zf2 : join with tablegateway dont work

Tags: php, sql, join, model, zend-framework2

I tried to make a join statement with tableGateway method wich one table 'A' that retrieve a field 'bfield' from other table 'B', in this  way on 'ATable' model:

```
public function getA($id){

    $id = (int) $id;
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select( function(Select $select) use ($id) {
        $select->join( 'B' , 'B.id = A.bfield_id' , array('bfield') )
            ->where->equalTo( 'A.id' , $id );
    });

    $row = $resultSet->current();

    return $row;

}
```

The problema is thar it dont return the 'bfield'. There are other way to do this that work, but return a simple array, and i need that return a 'A' object because i wil bind on edit form.

Whats missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

I got. I put the 'bfield' field in the model 'A' in the 'exchangeArray()' function list of vars and now it works.

Comment: This is because the TableGateway represents ONE TABLE. That is what the TableGateway-Pattern defines. JOINS are NOT for TableGateway :) Essentially your solution kind of breaks your Model-Layer though there are valid use-cases. As long as you only need one property that's fine. You may be interested to read [samsonasiks DbModelling](https://github.com/samsonasik/SanDbModellingWithZendDb/blob/master/src/SanDbModellingWithZendDb/Model/AlbumTrackMapper.php#L33)